# how to get number of rows updated and inserted from mysql

Tags: mysql

I'm doing large number of:

```
INSERT.... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
```

queries and I want to find out the number of rows affected, ideally the number updated and the number inserted.

At the moment I'm using ROW_COUNT() but that counts as 2 from the above sql if the row is updated or 1 if it is inserted.

Is there a way to find this from a mysql function?

Comment: i think the better way ist to run a update table first and then run the insert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`, the affected-rows value is `1`, if update its `2`. From this you can determine how many rows inserted successfully and how many are updated